# XNA 3.1 multiple sprites with different transform matrices?

Tags: c#, matrix, xna

I have 2 types of objects, one is 2D and will only face directly forward like a flat image, while the other will be 3D such that it scales and skews according to different rotations. So `SpriteBatch.Begin` applies the matrix to everything until I call `End`. I read somewhere that I should call `Begin` twice, once to draw the 2D sprites and once to draw the 3D objects but I don't know how I would change the matrix to fit each 3D object's needs and I'm very sad for not remembering what the link was.

So I wish to know how to do this without calling `Begin` and `End` on every object because that would be disastrous.

Comment: Why would calling Begin and End on every object be disastrous?

Comment: Well I haven't actually gotten around to trying this yet but the person who provided the solution in that missing link said it's a bad idea. If I do this on every object I'd be calling Begin and End up to 400 times everytime the Draw method is called and that doesn't sound very good..

Comment: Calling begin and end lots triggers lots of draw calls, which is bad. The OP is correct to try and avoid it.

Comment: Take a read of [this question and answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/optimizing-an-xna-2d-game) for more information about performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution here is to not use `SpriteBatch` for 3D drawing. **You should start using the actual 3D drawing API.**

`SpriteBatch` is merely a convenience layer over the top of the 3D API for 2D sprite drawing. You could, for example, write your own 3D version of `SpriteBatch`.

Within `SpriteBatch` there is no way to specify more than one transformation matrix to each batch. So if you have to have multiple matrices, you have to have multiple batches (multiple begin/end blocks).

If you're *really* keen on the `SpriteBatch`-based solution, then it is *possible* to do it that way - so you could try it and see how the performance is.

(You could also do a very ugly hack where you replace the vertex shader, somehow packing the 3D transformation data into each sprite, and then unpacking it in the shader. Ugly. Don't do it. [Edit: also overriding the `SpriteBatch` vertex shader is very difficult XNA before 4.0])